# Xamarin Insights in WPF app

Tags: xamarin

We are using xamarin for our android and iOS app. The shared code is also used in a WPF app for the Windows Platform (PC). 
Can i install and use Xamarin Insights in my shared project and log insights from my WPF app like I would do for Android and iOS app?

Comment: I don't see why not - did you try and use the Nuget package? Just need to make sure you have an active acount for Insights, it's not free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use Xamarin Insights in your Windows (WPF) application.
Take look at Insights docs for more information https://insights.xamarin.com/docs

Comment: Thanks! Do you thing the same Xamarin Insights dll will work across all platforms or i have to add a separate dll for each platform specific project?

Comment: @Kartik You need to add the Xamarin Insight nuget packages to your WPF project separately, it will automatically add the required DLLs

Comment: Yes go that. Xamarin Insights caches logs locally when the app is offline. Was wondering if those logs are encrypted or stored in plan text? Any clue?