# Xamarin insights web api

Tags: xamarin, reporting, asp.net-web-api

Can I use xamarin insights in a web api aplication?

I did not found if it's possible or not, and it crashes if I do anythin with xamarin insights in my web api.

I fond that it can be used in WPF,

[Xamarin Insights in WPF app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581557/xamarin-insights-in-wpf-app)

https://insights.xamarin.com/docs

so I supose that it can also be used in web api, but if someone can confirm this I will apreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use it in a WebApi project without problem. We are doing that as wel.

It is the type of platform that determines whether you can use Xamarin Insights. At the top of [this page in the Xamarin Documentation](https://insights.xamarin.com/docs) you can find the supported platforms.

It works excellent for error reporting. But you also can easily track events together with their properties (like RequestX was handled in Y seconds).

Have you considered using [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-get-started/)? Applicaton Insights includes a lot of functionality focussed at web applications (like your WebApi project).

Cheers,
Jacco

Comment: Thanks, great info, I did not know Application Insights, but it looks prety good to me.

Answer (score 1):

I asked it in the xamarins forums, and as it seems, it can be used in web api, but it's only good for Exception reporting, which is exactly wath I need.

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/105820#Comment_105820

I could not perform the test yet, but I will try It again.